# Append char to string with no value

Tags: c

How would I append a char to string that has no initial value in the following method I've started:

```
void append(char a) {
    const char *str;

    char *ret = malloc (strlen(str)+2);
    strncpy(str,strlen(str),ret);
    ret[strlen(str)-2] = a;
    ret[strlen(str)-1] = 0;

    printf("%s", str);
}
```

I've tried a few different answers to other questions but none have worked, please help.

Comment: You can't. `str` is not valid.

Comment: The logic in this doesn't make sense. `str` only has the scope of `append`, so what do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: Allocate at least two bytes for `str`, set `str[0] = a; str[1] = 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the pointer `str` is not initialized, you can't add characters to what it points at.  What makes sense depends on what you're going to do next. Since you don't return a value from the function, you can't access the string to which `a` is appended unless `append` calls some other function.

Answer (score 1):

`char *str;` is not a string. It is a mnemonic that says that **str will give you a value which is supposedly a character*.

`str` is a pointer that points at random. Make it point to an allocated bunch of memory first.
Do something like- `str = malloc(100);` and then do a `*(str+1) = a` and then a `*(str+2) = '\0'` to NULL terminate the string.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like:

```
char * append(char a, const char * str)
{
    char *ret = malloc (strlen(str)+2);
    strncpy(str,strlen(str),ret);
    ret[strlen(str)-2] = a;
    ret[strlen(str)-1] = 0;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I've done it differently and updated my original post. Why is mine giving me errors?